# ZeroMQ doesn't receive messages on EC2 from Local Machine

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, zeromq, pyzmq

I installed ZMQ on EC2 instance, I run a simple python script to receive messages from my local machine.

I use the Request-Reply Pattern to send and receive messages between the client (local machine) and the server (EC2).

here is my server script:

```
PORT = "5556" 
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % PORT)

while True:
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received Message From EDGE: ", message)  
    socket.send_string("Confirmation Message From Server Running on Port: %s" % PORT)
```

here is my local script:

```
PORT_SERVER = "5556"
context = zmq.Context()
print("Connecting to server...")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect ("tcp://52.211.232.41:%s" % PORT_SERVER)
socket.send_string("message from client!")
message = socket.recv()
print("Received Reply From Cloud :", message)
```

When I run both scripts nothing happend! However I tried to run them locally and they worked fine. 
I believe the problem is from the network configuration on the EC2.

Comment: Can you telnet your EC2 instance on 5556 port from the local PC? Do you add an  inbound rule in a security group where your EC2 instance is?

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue, so long as you've confirmed that the IP is correct.